# How can i link a group or verticies/edges/faces to be easily selected with the "L" key?

Tags: rigging, selection-tools

*I am not very experienced with blender so apologies if what I'm saying is either obvious or complete nonsense.* 
 I have a model with **4** separate parts that I would like to rig. [image: My model with all separate "parts" separated] 
 
 When I use the "L" key to select them, it selects mostly the entire piece but a few edges are left out and stick to the main mesh. 
 [image: Body of the gun selected with "L". Some faces are left out] 
 
 I have gone and manually selected these pieces and moved them out of the way for now, but when I need to rig it later, I will need to easily and quickly select them using the L shortcut. How can I join these faces and define a part to my model so I can select the entire body without missing these faces?

Comment: It's hard to understand, but L will select the vertices that are connected, not the ones that are separate. And of course it won't select any mesh that is not part of the same object

Comment: Clearly either UV seams aren't displayed for some reason - pressing Numpad + a few times helps in such situations - or unselected faces aren't connected to the rest of the piece. Try pressing A, M, B to merge all vertices by distance.

Answer (score 0):

It was just the vertices not being connected at some places. If anyone else encounters this problem, make sure all vertices are connected. Use the merge tool and select merge by distance and set it to something really small to get rid of those double vertices. Worked for me!